# "Google Cloud App Engine Messaging Starter" Project works fine locally but not deployed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

Although the JAVA "Google Cloud App Engine Messaging Starter" Project works fine locally with Eclipse, it won't communicate messages while actually deployed.  When I "register" from the Android Emulator, I get a message that everything "registered" successfully.  When I hit "send" on the App Engine side in the html window, nothing happens.  I have Wireshark Sniffer running, and I see messages on the network when I "register" between the Android and the App Engine.  When I try to hit "send" a message via the backend html side, I see no message traffic from the index.html to the cloud nor back down to the Android.  I see no complaints about endpoints in the app engine cloud log files so assume that is working.  Has anyone been able to get the App Engine Messaging Starter Project working recently?  I'm hoping it's not the latest google app engine sdk release.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to only exist in Windows 8 with any web browser, tried IE10 and Mozilla Firefox.  The javascript endpoint libraries that are not loading, load fine when using Internet Explorer on a Windows Phone 7 and from Windows 7 Pro desktop.  Figures, windows 8 pro is hosed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
1) You must run the index.html from the InternalWebBrowser of Eclipse.  You can bring up the InternalWebBrowser by selecting in Eclipse ==> Window->show view->other->general->InternalWebBrowser.
2) Then paste in your Application Default Version URL from your google App Engine "Application Settings" view.
3) Probably can do all this from a better browser but Windows 8 Pro 64-Bit Internet Explorer was giving me the problem in the first place.  It wouldn't execute the endpoint.sendMessage code.  Why, don't know right now.  Maybe microsoft's Azure is jealous, ha.